# POST from Angular to MVC controller in WebAPI project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API 2 solution which contains a mixture of ApiController (Web API) and Controller (MVC) controllers.

When I POST to my MVC controller from Angular I receive the following errors:

[image: error message]

I have tacked this down to the following section in the Web.Config file of the Web API project:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

If I comment out the `OPTIONSVerbHandler` and `<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" ...` lines then everything works fine.

Just to check I created a new MVC project and looked in the Web.Config file and this section does not exist so I assume it is still required by the Web API controllers.

What do I need to change in order to get this working without commenting out the aforementioned lines in the Web.Config file?

Comment: Is your GET endpoints working ?

Comment: I am doing an $http.post from Angular to MVC, with the lines commented out everything works ok - if I leave them in I get the error message

Comment: You did not answer my question ! Are the GET endpoints working fine ?

Comment: Yes, I have just added a dummy method to my MVC controller and a call to $http.get("http://localhost:4682/Parsers/GetSomething") works without any problems